# Adicionar classe conforme o texto por JS / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, classes

Estou estilizando radio-button e preciso adicionar classe conforme o texto do botão.
Na verdade é bem simples e funciona com o código abaixo, preciso que ao invés de inserir o **data-title=""** seja inserido como **class=""**

```
$('td').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).text());
});

Ou sem jQuery:

for (let el of document.getElementsByTagName('td')) {
  el.dataset.title = el.innerText.trim();
}
```

Não me lembro a maneira correta.

Comment: Cara não seria só trocar `data-title` por `class` nessa parte `$(this).attr('data-title', ...` ?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, me deu branco! Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com jQuery você pode gerenciar as classes com:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    const el = $(this);
    el.addClass( el.text() );
});
```

E sem jQuery basicamente a mesma coisa, captura o elemento e gerencia as classes

```
const el = document.querySelectorAll('td');
for (var i = 0, n = el.length; i < n; i++) {
    const element = el[i];
    element.classList.add( el.textContent );
}
```